# Scientific Term for "Mega Patents"

Tags: terminology

In a recent literature review, I have come across an ultra comprehensive patent ([US9583678B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9583678B2/en)), which documents the entire production process of high-power light-emitting diodes (and thus captures a large chunk of a company's IP in a single document).

Is there a scientific term (from meta-science or scientometrics) for these "mega patents"?

Comment: Other than over 400 reference cites is there something on the face of it that makes this stand out as unusual to you?

Comment: I quickly looked at the claims and they don’t seem broad at all? What makes you think this is a mega patent?

Comment: I don't think there is a "scientific" term for this or even a "technical" term. The patent is describing an LED fabrication process. There is a lot of prior art so in order to get granted, the patent is going to have to be specific enough to differentiate over that prior art.